# Unable to boot into/install Ubuntu Studio on new laptop (UEFI issue) either with or without Ventoy

Tags: boot, kubuntu, uefi

I have two computers: a desktop and a laptop. I also have a USB stick that I have installed Ventoy onto, and have thrown several Linux ISOs onto the Ventoy folder. Ubuntu Studio 20.10 is the distro I am using as my main right now (since I enjoy multimedia production), and I also want to dual-boot Windows. Vanilla Ubuntu and Kubuntu boot/install fine on both the desktop and laptop, and Ubuntu Studio installs on the desktop with no problem. However, the laptop is giving me issues. When I attempt to boot the ISO off Ventoy, I get this error:

[No Bootfile found for UEFI! Maybe the image does not support x64 UEFI!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0LNG.jpg)

I also used Startup Disk Creator to write the ISO to a different USB stick directly, but in that case the BIOS doesn't even recognize the stick as bootable:

[Can't boot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4cPS.jpg)

I'm not sure what's going on exactly, but it seems like there's some kind of issue with Ubuntu Studio and UEFI. I do need to maintain UEFI because I want to boot into Windows as well.

Desktop specs:

- Intel Pentium 3.3 GHz x 2
- 8 GB RAM

Laptop specs:

- Intel Core i7 2.6 GHz x 12
- 16 GB RAM

Comment: Please so not show pictures of text include the text in the question.

Comment: Just changed the first link! The second has no text per se.

Comment: I have a Ventoy USB with UB Studio on it and it loads OK, so perhaps 'No Bootfile found for UEFI! Maybe the image does not support x64 UEFI!' does not apply.